# Why is my conditional statement not working when trying to swap <p> text between 3 options in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the paragraph text when the next arrow is clicked. I can change it once but if I want to change it to a third option, it's not working. Can someone explain why this is the case?

I have made a Codepen with the issue: [Conditional statement problem](https://codepen.io/harrync92/pen/WNyJybM)

```
<div class="tutNavigation">
  <div class="flexNavigation">
    <div id="back"><i id="arrow-left"><-</i></div>
    <div class="tutorialText">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div id="next"><i id="arrow-right">-></i></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
let text = document.querySelector("p");
text.textContent = "text1";

let backLeft = document.getElementById("back");
let arrowBack = document.getElementById("arrow-left");

let nextRight = document.getElementById("next");
let arrowNext = document.getElementById("arrow-right");

if ((text.textContent = "text1")) {
  arrowBack.classList.add("hidden");
  nextRight.addEventListener("click", () => {
    arrowBack.classList.remove("hidden");
    text.textContent = "text2";
  });
  backLeft.addEventListener("click", () => {
    arrowBack.classList.add("hidden");
    text.textContent = "text1";
  });
} else if ((text.textcontent = "text2")) {
  nextRight.addEventListener("click", () => {
    text.textContent = "text3";
  });
  backLeft.addEventListener("click", () => {
    text.textContent = "text2";
  });
} else {
  text.textContent = "none";
}
```

Comment: `text.textcontent = "text2"` needs to change to `text.textcontent === "text2"`,`=` is assign value and `==` or `===` is compare value

Comment: Your JS logic is backwards - the `if` conditions should be inside the event handlers which you instantiate once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditions need to be added in the event listener and based on the conditions, hide or show elements

```js
let text = document.querySelector("p");
text.textContent = "text1";

let backLeft = document.getElementById("back");
let arrowBack = document.getElementById("arrow-left");

let nextRight = document.getElementById("next");
let arrowNext = document.getElementById("arrow-right");

arrowBack.classList.add("hidden");

nextRight.addEventListener("click", () => {
  arrowBack.classList.remove("hidden");
  if (text.textContent === "text1") {
    text.textContent = "text2";
  } else if (text.textContent === "text2") {
    text.textContent = "text3";
  }
});

backLeft.addEventListener("click", () => {

  if (text.textContent === "text3") {
    text.textContent = "text2";
  } else if (text.textContent === "text2") {
    text.textContent = "text1";
    arrowBack.classList.add("hidden");

  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.tutNavigation {
  display: flex;
  padding: 3rem 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0px -4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-content: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.tutNavigation.flexNavigation {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  gap: 1rem;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flexNavigation.tutorialText {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 500px;
}

p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.3rem;
}

#back,
#next {
  padding: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 72px;
}

i {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tutNavigation">
  <div class="flexNavigation">
    <div id="back"><i id="arrow-left"><-</i></div>
    <div class="tutorialText">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div id="next"><i id="arrow-right">-></i></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pull out the eventListerens form the conditions!
Beacouse you want to do something if you clicking on the arrows!

And inside the eventListeners you should write the logic.

```js
const text = document.querySelector("p");
const possiblities = ["text1", "text2", "text3", "text4"];
let index = 0;

let backLeft = document.getElementById("back");
let arrowBack = document.getElementById("arrow-left");

let nextRight = document.getElementById("next");
let arrowNext = document.getElementById("arrow-right");

const checkAndHideArrows = () => {
  if (index >= possiblities.length - 1) {
    nextRight.classList.add("hidden");
    arrowNext.classList.add("hidden");
    console.log("hide right");
  } else {
    nextRight.classList.remove("hidden")
    arrowNext.classList.remove("hidden")
    console.log("show right");
  }
  
  if (index <= 0) {
    backLeft.classList.add("hidden");
    arrowBack.classList.add("hidden");
    console.log("hide left");
  } else {
    backLeft.classList.remove("hidden");
    arrowBack.classList.remove("hidden");
    console.log("show left");
  }
}

const setText = () => {
  text.textContent = possiblities[index];
  console.log(possiblities[index]);
  checkAndHideArrows();
};

const next = () => {
  if (index++ >= possiblities.length - 1) {
    index = possiblities.length - 1;
  }
};

const prev = () => {
  if (index-- <= 0) {
    index = 0;
  }
};

setText();

nextRight.addEventListener("click", () => {
  next();
  console.log(index);
  setText();
});

backLeft.addEventListener("click", () => {
  prev();
  console.log(index);
  setText();
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="tutNavigation">
  <div class="flexNavigation">
    <div id="back"><i id="arrow-left"><-</i></div>
    <div class="tutorialText">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div id="next"><i id="arrow-right">-></i></div>
  </div>
</div>
```